# Merging two Data frames with fuzzy merge/sqldf

Tags: r

I have the following dataframes (df11 and df22) I'd like to do a merge/full join on with "UserID=UserID" and date difference <= 30 . So if the UserIDs match up AND the date's are less than or equal to 30, I'd like them merged into one singular row. I've looked at fuzzy join [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353869/create-group-based-on-fuzzy-criteria) and sqldf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64362881/finding-close-match-from-data-frame-1-in-data-fame-2) but I can't figure out how to implement either of those for my data frames.

```
df1 <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L), 
                      Full.Name = c( "John Smith", "Jack Peters", "Bob Brown", "Jane Doe", "Jackie Jane", "Sarah Brown", "Chloe Brown", "John Smith" ), 
                      Info = c("yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes"), 
                      EncounterID = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 13L), DateTime = c("1/2/21 00:00", "1/5/21 12:00", "1/1/21 1:31", "1/5/21 3:34", "5/9/21 5:33", "5/8/21 3:39", "12/12/21 2:30", "12/11/21 9:21"), 
                      Temp = c("100", "103", "104", "103", "101", "102", "103", "105"), 
 
                      misc = c("(null)", "no", "(null)", "(null)", "(null)","(null)", "(null)", "(null)" 
                                    )), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(UserID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), 
                      Full.Name = c("John Smith", "Jack Peters", "Bob Brown", "Jane Doe", "Jackie Jane", "Sarah Brown"), 
                      DOB = c("1/1/90", "1/10/90", "1/2/90", "2/20/80", "2/2/80", "12/2/80"), 
                      EncounterID = c(13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), EncounterDate = c("1/1/21", "1/2/21", "1/1/21", "1/6/21", "5/7/21", "5/8/21"), 
                      Type = c("Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Intro", "Care", "Out"), 
                      responses = c("(null)", "no", 
                                    "yes", "no", "no", "unsat")), 
                      
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -6L))
loadedNamespaces()
install.packages("Rcpp")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)

df11 <- 
df1 %>% 
  separate(DateTime, c("Date", "Time"), sep=" ") %>% 
  mutate(Date = as_datetime(mdy(Date))) %>% 
  select(-Time) %>% 
  as_tibble()

df22 <-
df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate), mdy)) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(EncounterDate), as_datetime)) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

@r2evans After running the first set of code, I get the following output. Which is slightly different from yours.

```
df11 <- mutate(df11, Date_m30 = Date %m-% days(30), Date_p30 = Date %m+% days(30))
df11
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  UserID Full.Name   Info  EncounterID Date                Temp  misc  
   <int> <chr>       <chr>       <int> <dttm>              <chr> <chr> 
1      1 John Smith  yes            13 2021-01-02 00:00:00 100   (null)
2      2 Jack Peters no             14 2021-01-05 00:00:00 103   no    
3      3 Bob Brown   yes            15 2021-01-01 00:00:00 104   (null)
4      4 Jane Doe    yes            16 2021-01-05 00:00:00 103   (null)
5      5 Jackie Jane yes            17 2021-05-09 00:00:00 101   (null)
6      6 Sarah Brown yes            18 2021-05-08 00:00:00 102   (null)
7      7 Chloe Brown no             19 2021-12-12 00:00:00 103   (null)
8      1 John Smith  yes            13 2021-12-11 00:00:00 105   (null)
```

Comment: It's great that you provided the output from `dput`, thank you! It's an uncommon perk in questions. However ... the conversion of columns to `Date`-class or `POSIXct`-class objects should have nothing to do with your merging issues. Please *minimize* your question, showing only code that is relevant. (That is, update the columns and redo the `dput` portion. Don't include `loadedNamespaces` or `install.packages`. Keep the `library` calls.) Thanks!

Comment: What did you try from `sqldf` or other fuzzy-join attempts?

Comment: There is something really broken if you `mutate` to add `Date_m30` and it does not appear in the output.

Comment: I've tried it on 3 machines and I've gotten # A tibble: 8 x 7 on each one of them. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I have no idea why `mutate` would not return the additional columns. Try `df11$Date %m-% days(30)` and see if it returns what you expect. If yes, check that the `+`-variant also works. If yes, then check for typos in the name of the stored object, perhaps `df11` or `dfl1` (lower-`L` versus one-`1`), or something else that could possibly be causing this dilemma.

Comment: I re ran all the packages and libraries and it worked. You're amazing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to first create "+/- 30 day" columns in one of them, then do a standard date-range join. Using `sqldf`:

Prep:

```r
library(dplyr)
df11 <- mutate(df11, Date_m30 = Date %m-% days(30), Date_p30 = Date %m+% days(30))
df11
# # A tibble: 8 x 9
#   UserID Full.Name   Info  EncounterID Date                Temp  misc   Date_m30            Date_p30           
#    <int> <chr>       <chr>       <int> <dttm>              <chr> <chr>  <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1      1 John Smith  yes            13 2021-01-02 00:00:00 100   (null) 2020-12-03 00:00:00 2021-02-01 00:00:00
# 2      2 Jack Peters no             14 2021-01-05 00:00:00 103   no     2020-12-06 00:00:00 2021-02-04 00:00:00
# 3      3 Bob Brown   yes            15 2021-01-01 00:00:00 104   (null) 2020-12-02 00:00:00 2021-01-31 00:00:00
# 4      4 Jane Doe    yes            16 2021-01-05 00:00:00 103   (null) 2020-12-06 00:00:00 2021-02-04 00:00:00
# 5      5 Jackie Jane yes            17 2021-05-09 00:00:00 101   (null) 2021-04-09 00:00:00 2021-06-08 00:00:00
# 6      6 Sarah Brown yes            18 2021-05-08 00:00:00 102   (null) 2021-04-08 00:00:00 2021-06-07 00:00:00
# 7      7 Chloe Brown no             19 2021-12-12 00:00:00 103   (null) 2021-11-12 00:00:00 2022-01-11 00:00:00
# 8      1 John Smith  yes            13 2021-12-11 00:00:00 105   (null) 2021-11-11 00:00:00 2022-01-10 00:00:00
```

The join:

```r
sqldf::sqldf("
    select df11.*, df22.DOB, df22.EncounterDate, df22.Type, df22.responses
    from df11
      left join df22 on df11.UserID = df22.UserID
        and df22.EncounterDate between df11.Date_m30 and df11.Date_p30") %>%
  select(-Date_m30, -Date_p30)
#   UserID   Full.Name Info EncounterID                Date Temp   misc     DOB       EncounterDate  Type responses
# 1      1  John Smith  yes          13 2021-01-01 19:00:00  100 (null)  1/1/90 2020-12-31 19:00:00 Intro    (null)
# 2      2 Jack Peters   no          14 2021-01-04 19:00:00  103     no 1/10/90 2021-01-01 19:00:00 Intro        no
# 3      3   Bob Brown  yes          15 2020-12-31 19:00:00  104 (null)  1/2/90 2020-12-31 19:00:00 Intro       yes
# 4      4    Jane Doe  yes          16 2021-01-04 19:00:00  103 (null) 2/20/80 2021-01-05 19:00:00 Intro        no
# 5      5 Jackie Jane  yes          17 2021-05-08 20:00:00  101 (null)  2/2/80 2021-05-06 20:00:00  Care        no
# 6      6 Sarah Brown  yes          18 2021-05-07 20:00:00  102 (null) 12/2/80 2021-05-07 20:00:00   Out     unsat
# 7      7 Chloe Brown   no          19 2021-12-11 19:00:00  103 (null)    <NA>                <NA>  <NA>      <NA>
# 8      1  John Smith  yes          13 2021-12-10 19:00:00  105 (null)    <NA>                <NA>  <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my post in the end to show my output with your first set of code. It won't work. My tibble is 8 x 7 whereas yours is 8 x 9. Do you know why?